# Erro em página JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou fazendo uma página em JSP, onde o usuário informa 2 valores e através de um método, eu faço a soma desses 2 valores e apresenta logo abaixo o valor do resultado.

Porém a página não está nem carregando, está apresentando erro na linha 17, onde estou declarando a primeira variável ao valor ddo "input" que o usuário informou.

Já tentei alterar o "input type" pra "number" ou "text", porém ele continua com o erro. E se eu alterar o "form" para submeter para outra página, ele funciona normal (desde que eu declare as variáveis na outra página).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Código da página JSP**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Exercício 6</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Informe 2 números</h1>
  <form>
   Valor 1: <input type="number" name="valor1" /><br><br>
   Valor 2: <input type="number" name="valor2" /><br><br>
   <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <%
   int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor1"));
   int valor2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor2"));
  %>
  <h2>Resultado do cálculo</h2>
  <%!
   public static int resultado(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
   }
  %>
  <div><%=resultado(valor1,valor2)%></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Erro**

```html
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /soma.jsp at line 17

14:    <input type="submit" />
15:   </form>
16:   <%
17:    int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor1"));
18:    int valor2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor2"));
19:   %>
20:   <h2>Resultado do cálculo</h2>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root Cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jsp.soma_jsp._jspService(soma_jsp.java:130)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando pegar informações do request dentro do scriplet, mas o objeto de request com os valores do formulário só vai existir quando você enviar o form. Por isso está ocorrendo o null pointer, e por isso funciona quando envia pra outra página.

O correto aí é enviar para outra página mesmo, seguindo o fluxo normal do JSP. Pra ficar tudo em uma página só, teria que fazer os scripts com Javascript.

Se precisar de mais alguma informação fique à vontade para perguntar.

Boa sorte!